# Where do I initialize or put my Client ID so I can make SOAP calls?

Tags: python, soap, zeep

So I have a username and password, and I have a ClientID. With JSON I can just create a header field to add these in and do a requests.post(endpoint, json=payload, headers=my_headers), but for SOAP the header fields are {content-type': 'application/soap+xml'} and auth= takes username and password. So what happens to my ClientID or where do I initialize it?

First I will start off with what I tried using Zeep for Python.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests import Session
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep import Client, Settings

#Client-ID
client_id = '7777'

username = 'jj'
password = 'tt'

#this endpoint ends with .svc, not sure if that matters but even if I were to add ?wsdl I get 400 error
wsdl = 'endpoint_url_.svc'

settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)


session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
client = Client(wsdl, settings=settings, # the Client field here doesn't take ClientID but my endpoint
            transport=Transport(session=session))
```

So Zeep says to run python -mzeep wsdl to get soap methods but this is my output:
Prefixes:
xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Global elements:

Global types:
xsd:anyType
xsd:ENTITIES
xsd:ENTITY
xsd:ID
xsd:IDREF
xsd:IDREFS
xsd:NCName
xsd:NMTOKEN
xsd:NMTOKENS
xsd:NOTATION
xsd:Name
xsd:QName
xsd:anySimpleType
xsd:anyURI
xsd:base64Binary
xsd:boolean
xsd:byte
xsd:date
xsd:dateTime
xsd:decimal
xsd:double
xsd:duration
xsd:float
xsd:gDay
xsd:gMonth
xsd:gMonthDay
xsd:gYear
xsd:gYearMonth
xsd:hexBinary
xsd:int
xsd:integer
xsd:language
xsd:long
xsd:negativeInteger
xsd:nonNegativeInteger
xsd:nonPositiveInteger
xsd:normalizedString
xsd:positiveInteger
xsd:short
xsd:string
xsd:time
xsd:token
xsd:unsignedByte
xsd:unsignedInt
xsd:unsignedLong
xsd:unsignedShort

Bindings:

So even if I do this, none of my methods show at service.
result = client.service.(some method)

2. Second attempt without Zeep. Now for some reason the soap data example for the body looks like this.

   import requests
   from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

   soap_body = '''

   1

   D

   0

   ex

   5
   '''

From examples and SOAP calls I've read and seen online it is missing envelope, body, and header, but let's assume this is the correct xml for making the post request.

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
url = 'endpoint_url.svc'

username = 'jj'
password= 'tt'
client_id = '7777'

response = requests.post(url, data=soap_body, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
print(response)
print(response.content)
```

Ouput I get
<Response [415]>
b''

The requests.post doesn't seem to take a ClientID field. How would I initialize this first? Any suggestions or recommendations appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: For some reason my soap body didn't turn out right, but here is how its suppose to look like <ConfirmApp xmlns="urn:stems-com:PAM.2010.Service" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!--string occurs:0,1-->
  <ID xsi:nil="false">1</ID>
  <!--string occurs:0,1-->
  <IDType xsi:nil="false">T</IDType>
  <!--string occurs:0,1-->
  <MID xsi:nil="false">1</MID>
  <!--string occurs:0,1-->
  <MIDType xsi:nil="false">ex</MIDType>
  <!--string occurs:0,1-->
  <AID xsi:nil="false">5</AID>
</ConfirmApp>

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find this in a documentation anywhere, but the Client ID can be placed inside the headers as well. `headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml', 'Client-ID':'123'}`